# XPath - Get child elements without a specific id

Tags: xpath, web

I have tried refraining from asking for help, but I have had enough! I am trying to get the child elements of a node; all except one with a particular id. This is what I have thus far:

```
//*[@id='a']/*[@id!='b']
```

It works to some extent. It gets all child elements of 'a' that do not have an id of 'b', but I want it to get all child elements, regardless whether it has an id attribute or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Phil has already given the solution but it's perhaps worth noting why your expression doesn't mean what you intended. The simplest rule for using `!=` in xpath is don't use it, it rarely means what was intended. Infix condiditionals _all_ have an implied _exists_ quantification so `@id!='b'` means "there exists an id attribute not equal to 'b'" which as you observe is not true if there is no id attribute. `not(@id='b')` means: it's not the case that there exists an id attribute that is equal to 'b'.

Comment: Thanks David, I didn't know that. I'm relatively inexperienced to using XPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `not()`, eg

```
//*[@id="a"]/*[not(@id="b")]
```